# Topshelf service doesn't send email

Tags: c#, .net, topshelf

I developed a service using Topshelf to send some server statistics via email.
All is ok an works fine under Visual Studio 2017 execution, but (always exists about...) when the service is installed and started, the just send emails to gmail.com, yahoo.com and others populars emails services. But not for the email associated to my company. It is curious because when I execute the service as solution under VS2017 it's sends fine to ANY email address.

To sum up: 
-If I execute the solution via the VS2017 IDE then the solution sends to any email address.
-If I install the service and start it, it just send to typically emails addres like gmail.com, yahoo.com, etc.. BUT not to the address associated to my company.

BTW: Outlook is not filtering any email address.

```
#region Send email using a simple SMPT .net client
private bool SendEmail(Email d)
{
    bool resul = false;

    try
    {
        MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
        SmtpClient SmtpClient = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");
        mail.From = new MailAddress(d.EmailAddress);
        mail.To.Add(d.EmailAddress);
        mail.Subject = d.Subject;
        LinkedResource linkedImg = new LinkedResource(@"charts\\mockChart.jpg");
        linkedImg.ContentId = "mockChart";
        linkedImg.ContentType = new ContentType(MediaTypeNames.Image.Jpeg);

        AlternateView htmlView = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(
            "Dear Mr/Ms " + d.Name + " " + d.surname1 +
            "</br></br>" + d.Body + "\n <img src=charts\\mockChart.jpg>",
            null, "text/html");

        htmlView.LinkedResources.Add(linkedImg);
        mail.AlternateViews.Add(htmlView);

        mail.Attachments.Add(new System.Net.Mail.Attachment("charts\\mockChart.jpg"));

        SmtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
        SmtpClient.Port = 587;
        SmtpClient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("anemail@address.com", "blablabla");
        SmtpClient.EnableSsl = true;

        SmtpClient.Send(mail);
        resul = true;
        Console.WriteLine(FileController.writeDataIntoALog("MAIL SENT TO " + d.EmailAddress, FileController.fileStr));
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.Append(e.Message);
        sb.Append(e.StackTrace);
        FileController.writeDataIntoALog(sb.ToString(), FileController.fileStr);
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        resul = false;
    }

    return resul;
}
```

This is an easy code that works!... but... :( but such I said just send to corporative emails under Visual Studio execution.

BTW: I am using a Exchange server, but I can't make a SOAP request to send emails under the Exchange server, If I have the code if anybody wants to see it.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: What is the error, if any?

Comment: Apparently there is not an error, in fact the code works fine, I think is a net problem or server problem, but I am not preatty sure, because such I said it works fine when I execute under VS.

Comment: If you are not getting an error that would imply it has been sent. If you are not receiving it, it must be getting filtered. Where is the service running, is this a different machine?

Comment: No, is in the same machine, but is not filtering because (I belive), because executing the solution under VS2017 the email is sent correctly, but, installed as a service, in the same machine with WIN7, the corportaive email (not gmail.com, yahoo.com) is no sent.

Answer (score 0):

**AHAAA!** ;-) Solved!

The problem was that my VS2017 was running under my account with administrator permissions, but, the installed service wasn't use my account with this permissions.

Services.exe --> Right click over the service --> Properties --> Start Session Tab, and check for the correct account.

[image: Service Permisssions]

PS: Excuse me for my "Spanish Screenshot" ;-)